# GDataXML - xpath min function not found

Tags: objective-c, xml, xpath, gdataxml

I want to use xpath min function in my app, but it seems it's not registered.
Is there any way I could get it to work?
I don't want to create loops if there's something that could help me avoid clutter in code.

I'm using and libxml2, ios sdk 4.3

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 defines a min function, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-min. If you use an XPath 1.0 implementation then the min function is not supported, see http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5121.html#d6613e292 on how to find a minumum with XPath 1.0.

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like something that can be used withough xpath2, however I am looking for a way to use xpath2 on ios with gdataxml - mostly because there will probably be other functions I would like to use later on.